# How to do & plot simple and rolling linear regression on financial data xts object in R?

Tags: r, time-series, regression, xts

Working with 30 minute data, of which I have put a sample online. It's the notional dollar value of the spread between ES and 2 contracts of NQ (ES-2*NQ). Sample is small, but should be long enough to use directly in a demo if you like. R code to grab it and use it as I am trying to:

```
demo.xts <- as.xts(read.zoo('http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31394273/demo.csv', sep=',', tz = '', header = TRUE, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

head(demo.xts):

```
                        [,1]
2013-05-27 00:00:00 -37295.0
2013-05-27 00:30:00 -37292.5
2013-05-27 01:00:00 -37300.0
2013-05-27 01:30:00 -37280.0
2013-05-27 02:00:00 -37190.0
2013-05-27 02:30:00 -37245.0
```

What I am mainly after is a rolling window regression (or [linear regression curve](http://demo.thinkorswim.com/manual/dark/thinkscript/reference/Functions/Statistical/Inertia.html), as my trading platform terms it) - save it, then plot it. And, I figured to lead up to that I should be able to also plot a single simple regression for a specified time period. After the window regression, I would add standard deviation "bands" to that, but I think I can figure that one out later using TTR's "runSD" on the rolling regression. Sample of what I am after:

[image: chart with hand drawn lines]

I think this - [Rolling regression xts object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324362/rolling-regression-xts-object-in-r) - got me the closest to what I think I am after. It seemed to work with my data, but I couldn't figure out how to turn the resulting "coefficients" into a line or curve in the notional dollar value plot I want to work with.

Referencing any package (like TTR) would be great; happy to load anything that makes this more simple or easy.

Comment: I can't figure out how the "standard deviation bands" would be calculated. Can you provide a formula?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich the way i understand it it is the linear regression curve ± number of standard deviations times the price. so, using your sample code below, it seems like `rma + 2*runSD(demo.xts, n=20)` works to add the "upper band," for example. also, the other answer by vincent seems to come up with a similar result as expected with the "lwr" and "upr" that the predict function outputs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `predict` to compute the points on the regression line
and `tail` to extract the most recent one.

```
# Sample data
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC", from="2009-01-01")

# Rolling regression (unweighted), with prediction intervals
x <- rollapplyr( 
  as.zoo(Ad(GSPC)), 
  width=300, by.column = FALSE, 
  FUN = function(x) {
    r <- lm( x ~ index(x) )
    tail(predict(r, interval="prediction"),1)
  } 
)

# Plots
plot( index(GSPC), Ad(GSPC), type="l", lwd=3, las=1 )
lines( index(x), x$fit, col="purple", lwd=3 )
lines( index(x), x$lwr, col="purple", lwd=3, lty=3 )
lines( index(x), x$upr, col="purple", lwd=3, lty=3 )
abline( lm( Ad(GSPC) ~ index(GSPC) ), col="light blue", lwd=3 )
```

[image: Moving regression]

Comment: this works very well. i hadn't come across the predict function, and probably wouldn't have ever thought to explore it. that it also includes the standard deviations is great. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I've recently added a `rollSFM` (rolling single-factor model) function to TTR.  Here's an example of running a 24 period rolling regression:

```
reg <- rollSFM(demo.xts, .index(demo.xts), 24)
rma <- reg$alpha + reg$beta*.index(demo.xts)
chart_Series(demo.xts, TA="add_TA(rma,on=1)")
```

[image]

The basic idea is to regress your prices on time. `.index` returns the numeric representation of the POSIXct index of `demo.xts` (i.e. the number of seconds since the epoch), so the second argument is time.  `rma` contains the fitted value for the linear regression at each point in time (the `reg` object also contains R-squared).

Comment: this also answers my question, but i'm not allowed to checkmark both. i have to admit i didn't know what a single factor model was, so it was totally not on my radar. works great! btw, your packages are so useful. i wouldn't even fathom trying to attempt backtesting in R if they didn't exist. thank you.