# Trying to use the window function from R

Tags: r

This is my dataframe:

```
structure(list(dates = structure(c(16162, 16161, 16160, 16157, 
16156, 16155, 16154, 16153, 16150, 16149, 16148, 16147, 16146, 
16143, 16142, 16141, 16140, 16139, 16136, 16135, 16134, 16129, 
16128, 16127, 16126, 16125, 16122, 16121, 16120, 16119, 16118, 
16115, 16114, 16113, 16112, 16111, 16108, 16107, 16106, 16105, 
16104, 16101, 16100, 16099, 16098, 16097, 16094, 16093, 16092, 
16091), class = "Date"), VALE5 = c(28.29, 28.26, 28.35, 27.81, 
27.85, 27.5, 27.61, 27.16, 27.2, 26.64, 26.57, 26.55, 26, 26.1, 
25.9, 26.46, 26.1, 26.37, 27.09, 28.11, 28.11, 29.09, 29.31, 
29.02, 29, 29.76, 30.61, 30.59, 30.9, 30.6, 30.74, 30.96, 30.76, 
30.79, 30.77, 30.44, 30.66, 30.8, 29.94, 29.58, 29.1, 30, 29.76, 
29.96, 28.88, 28.54, 28.63, 28.15, 28.91, 28.48)), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to set the window function like this:

```
window(sample,start=c(2014,03,26),end=c(2014,04,02))
```

What is wrong with my `sample` dataframe? The dates column has the class `Date`. It is not enough to use the `window` function?

How can I fix it?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think `window` is supposed to be used for `ts` class time series objects, while you have a `data.frame`. Are you just trying to select rows in a particular period like `sample[sample$dates >= "2014-03-26" & sample$dates <= "2014-04-02",]` ?

Comment: @thelatemail thanks. Yes. But after select the dates I will roll this window. I will estimate a OLS regression.  Is it possible to do the rolling with `sample[sample$dates >= "2014-03-26" & sample$dates <= "2014-04-02",]` idea?

Comment: This should be possible but is not something I've personally done - you might want to look into the `zoo` package which has many `roll*` functions, in particular `rollapply` which will allow you to apply an arbitrary function to a moving/rolling window of values. See here for an example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324362/rolling-regression-xts-object-in-r

Comment: I edited the sample size. How could I have windows of the size 10 moving each day. This is what I want.

Answer (score 7):

**1) window.zoo** `window` is meant for time series objects like `ts` and `zoo`.  `ts` is not appropriate for daily data but you can convert `sample` to a zoo object and then run it like this:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(sample)
window(z, start = "2014-03-26", end = "2014-04-02")
```

giving:

```
           BBAS3 BBDC3 VALE5
2014-03-26 21.11 31.53 27.50
2014-03-27 22.51 33.38 27.85
2014-03-28 22.22 33.20 27.81
2014-03-31 22.80 33.59 28.35
2014-04-01 22.78 33.75 28.26
2014-04-02 22.85 33.82 28.29
```

**2) subset** This base approach would also work but does not use `window`:

```
subset(sample, dates >= "2014-03-26" & dates <= "2014-04-02")
```

**3) xts** With xts this notation can be used.  `z` is from (1) above:

```
library(xts)

x <- as.xts(z)
x["2014-03-26/2014-04-02"]
```

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck. It would be possible to move this window by the dates? I will set the last ten dates and running a lm regression. After another window with ten dates and another lm regressio.

Comment: You can do things like this: `rollapplyr(z, 3, function(x) coef(lm(as.data.frame(x))), by.column = FALSE)`